# How to programmatically get the exact address in the memory space according to the assembly statement

Tags: linux, assembly, x86

Hummm,hope i will express my question clearly.

Now i have an assembly statement string like:

```
movss ****,xmm0; (intel style)
```

After this assembly statement being executed, a piece of the process's memory changed. 
So `****` must be the memory address, it could be something like:

```
DWORD PTR [eax],
DWORD PTR [eax + 0x4],
DWORD PTR [ebp - 0x4]
...Some style i have not seen, if you know that, please do tell me.
```

My problem is how to programmatically get the memory address through analyzing the assembly statement string.

For example:
if `****` to be :

```
DWORD PTR [eax]
```

Perhaps I could search the string, and find  EAX register, then get the data from EAX register, maybe it is the memory address, maybe not, it depends on the Addressing System, am i right? Finally，how could i get the exact address？

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to achieve. Why can't you just stick in there your `DWORD PTR [eax]`, what prevents you from doing just that?

Comment: @Alex  Actually，the assembly statement not belong to my process, i read the machine instruction from other running process's memory space,then translate it to assembly statement. I want to know that where this machine instruction writes to in the running process's memory space.

Comment: Then you need to have the register state of that process and disassemble its instructions. You most likely need to use some debugging and/or virtualizing tools in order to be able not only to disassemble but also know all operands at run time.

Comment: Now i could programmaticall yget the register state and could disassemble its instructions, actually i write a small debugger refer to gdb source code. But after i get the assembly statement, i don't know how to do next step =_=.

Comment: You read the CPU manual to see how different instructions access memory and get actual addresses from the instruction (most instructions use the MOD R/M byte optionally followed by SIB byte optionally followed by a displacement) and registers. Every [eax], [ebx+4], [ecx*4+edi+3], [bp+si] has a special encoding. You need to know if an instruction accesses memory and how. The manual has all the info about it.

Comment: I know this instruction do write the memory(the write opt is mov, am i wright?), as mentioned above,movss DWORD PTR [eax],xmm0; the ope is movss. But how do cpu know the actual addresses? Just according to DWORD PTR [eax]？ is there any issuer to opt mov?

Comment: In this case the actual address is in eax.

Comment: OK, see the problem, if I know this instruction do write the memory, and get the assembly statement string: movss +++,xmm0; ('+++' could be anything stand for the address), how to calculate the address. Perhaps: if([eax]) { address = value of [eax];} if([eax+0x24]) { address = value of [eax] + 0x24;} if([eax]){ address = value of [dei] + value of[eax];}...............

Comment: That's the idea. But in a few instructions the address isn't explicitly shown as a memory operand. Take, for example, `pop eax` (reads from [esp]) or `movsb` (reads from [esi], writes to [edi]).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10632/discussion-between-alangame-and-alex)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible for you to use the `LEA` "Load Effective Address" instruction ? I'm sorry, I'm not too familiar with Intel assembly, but that's what I would try.

This may help: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/Data_Transfer#Load_Effective_Address

Hope this helps!

Comment: Powerful instruction,any for arm?